Docker build for ASP.NET Core 8 return error Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
I want to create a Docker image for my ASP.NET Core 8 application. The Dockerfile must be located in the root directory of the git repository, as shown in the attached image. When I place the Dockerfile inside the API project, everything works fine, but I need to keep it in the application's root directory.

Here is my dockerfile:
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["LibraryApp/*.sln", "./"]
COPY ["LibraryApp/LibraryApp.Api/LibraryApp.Api.csproj", "LibraryApp.Api/"]
COPY ["LibraryApp/LibraryApp.Dtos/LibraryApp.Dtos.csproj", "LibraryApp.Dtos/"]
COPY ["LibraryApp/LibraryApp.Infrastructure/LibraryApp.Infrastructure.csproj", "LibraryApp.Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["LibraryApp/LibraryApp.Services/LibraryApp.Services.csproj", "LibraryApp.Services/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./LibraryApp.sln"

RUN dotnet restore "./LibraryApp.Api/LibraryApp.Api.csproj"
COPY . .

WORKDIR "/src/LibraryApp.Api"
RUN dotnet build "./LibraryApp.Api.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build
#RUN dotnet publish -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./LibraryApp.Api.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "LibraryApp.Api.dll"]

when I build it using docker build -t libraryapp. i am getting error.
>  => ERROR [build 12/12] RUN dotnet build "./LibraryApp.Api.csproj" -c
> Release -o /app/build                                                 
> 10.6s
> ------
>  > [build 12/12] RUN dotnet build "./LibraryApp.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build:
> 1.836   Determining projects to restore...
> 3.474   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
> 8.368   LibraryApp.Dtos -> /app/build/LibraryApp.Dtos.dll
> 8.416   LibraryApp.Infrastructure -> /app/build/LibraryApp.Infrastructure.dll
> 8.999   LibraryApp.Services -> /app/build/LibraryApp.Services.dll
> 10.46 CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
> [/src/LibraryApp.Api/LibraryApp.Api.csproj]
> 10.48
> 10.49 Build FAILED.
> 10.49
> 10.49 CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
> [/src/LibraryApp.Api/LibraryApp.Api.csproj]
> 10.49     0 Warning(s)
> 10.49     1 Error(s)
> 10.49
> 10.49 Time Elapsed 00:00:09.70
> ------ WARNING: current commit information was not captured by the build: git was not found in the system: exec: "git.exe": executable
> file not found in %PATH% Dockerfile:23
> --------------------   21 |   22 |     WORKDIR "/src/LibraryApp.Api"   23 | >>> RUN dotnet build "./LibraryApp.Api.csproj" -c
> $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build   24 |     #RUN dotnet publish -c
> $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build   25 |
> -------------------- ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c dotnet build \"./LibraryApp.Api.csproj\" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o
> /app/build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1


I have tried everything and searched a lot but have not been able to fix it.
Anything that helps me resolve this issue would be appreciated.
Thanks

Would it possible to provide sample of Program.cs from LibraryApp.Api project?. if you can provide reproducible github repo with sample project, it would be nice.
